# SQL Server CASE statement in Where Clause of Select

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to select from a table using a case statement in the WHERE clause.  This is a stored procedure which takes several input strings.  I have a variable @Region which can have values of ('ALL','NE','NY','PA').

I'm trying to do the something like this:

```
SELECT sum(ElectricTotalBudgetCost)
FROM dbo.Properties 
WHERE aYear=@ParamYear and aMonth=@ParamMonth AND
Properties.StateRegion=
    CASE
        WHEN  @Region ='ALL' THEN '%'
        ELSE @Region
    END
```

In place of the '%', I've also tried IS NOT NULL. I've also tried to use WHEN @Region='ALL' THEN LIKE '%'

In all cases there is a syntax problem or there is a NULL result when 'ALL' is passed to the procedure. My guess is that I'm looking at this the wrong way. I've spent many hours researching and can't seem to think of another way to accomplish this. I'm fairly new to SQL and would appreciate any help people might be able to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe instead of :

```
 CASE
        WHEN  @Region ='ALL' THEN '%'
        ELSE @Region
    END
```

use:

```
 CASE
        WHEN  @Region ='ALL' THEN Properties.StateRegion
        ELSE @Region
    END
```

This assumes when 'ALL' is selected, you want to apply no filtering.
It further assumes @Region will contain only one value of ('NE','NY','PA') not multiple; and that NE, NY, and PA are values in Properties.StateRegion

Comment: Thanks very much!  That did it for me.  (All of your assumptions were correct)

Answer (score 3):

You're actually trying to do this?

```
SELECT sum(ElectricTotalBudgetCost)
FROM dbo.Properties 
WHERE aYear=@ParamYear and aMonth=@ParamMonth AND
(Properties.StateRegion=@Region or @Region = 'ALL')
```

This will return all rows if "ALL" is the value of @Region

Answer (score 0):

You could change the statement to use `Properties.StateRegion LIKE @Region` instead and before your `SELECT` statement you can use this IF statement:

```
IF @Region = 'ALL'
BEGIN
    SET @Region = '%'
END
```

Using `LIKE` will help match your column with any word in @Region and the `%` character will help find all columns.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I chose another answer because I may need to do this all in one select at times.  Your method will go into my SQL tool bag!